# WebApi JSON Output

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

So I created a WebApi project in MVC4 and was having trouble understanding the JSON output. I'm not entirely sure if this is the intended output of JSON or if i have done something incorrectly.

I have three tables, (pb_Project, pb_Tasks and pb_Priority). The relationship are as follows:
Project may have many tasks, and Each project can have one priority level.

[entities http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9294/stackoverflowentities.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9294/stackoverflowentities.png)

Now, the output that I am receiving is quite odd and not really intuitive.  I'm not sure if this is the intended JSON (as I am brand new to it). When I run the website to retrieve the JSON output for the projects I get the following result.

```
[

    {
        "$id": "1",
        "pb_Priority": {
            "$id": "2",
            "pb_Projects": [
                {
                    "$ref": "1"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "pb_Priority": {
                        "$ref": "2"
                    },
                    "pb_Tasks": [
                        {
                            "$id": "4",
                            "pb_Projects": {
                                "$ref": "3"
                            },
                            "TASK_ID": 3,
                            "PROJECT_ID": 2,
                            "USER_ID": 2,
                            "DUE_DATE": "2012-11-19T00:00:00",
                            "PRIORITY_ID": 2,
                            "TASK_NAME": "project 2 task 1",
                            "DESCRIPTION": "asdf"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PROJECT_ID": 2,
                    "USER_ID": 2,
                    "NAME": "Project2",
                    "DESCRIPTION": "project 2 description",
                    "BUDGET": 1,
                    "LOCATION": "CANADA",
                    "START_DATE": "2012-11-18T00:00:00",
                    "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
                    "PROJ_SCALE": null,
                    "NOTES": null
                }
            ],
            "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
            "PRIORITY_LEVEL": 1
        },
        "pb_Tasks": [
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "pb_Projects": {
                    "$ref": "1"
                },
                "TASK_ID": 1,
                "PROJECT_ID": 1,
                "USER_ID": 1,
                "DUE_DATE": "2012-11-19T00:00:00",
                "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
                "TASK_NAME": "project 1 task 1",
                "DESCRIPTION": "adsf"
            },
            {
                "$id": "6",
                "pb_Projects": {
                    "$ref": "1"
                },
                "TASK_ID": 2,
                "PROJECT_ID": 1,
                "USER_ID": 2,
                "DUE_DATE": "2012-11-19T00:00:00",
                "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
                "TASK_NAME": "project 1 task 2 user 2",
                "DESCRIPTION": "asd"
            }
        ],
        "PROJECT_ID": 1,
        "USER_ID": 1,
        "NAME": "Project1",
        "DESCRIPTION": "project 1 description",
        "BUDGET": 1000,
        "LOCATION": "USA",
        "START_DATE": "2012-11-18T00:00:00",
        "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
        "PROJ_SCALE": null,
        "NOTES": null
    },
    {
        "$ref": "3"
    }

]
```

The controller for this is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<pb_Projects> Getpb_Projects()
{
    return db.pb_Projects.AsEnumerable();
}
```

What I would expect from this json result would be a list of Projects(objects) with any other relative FK's and such. Whereas here I get one big object, with another ref as the 2nd object. Am i doing something wrong, i would expect something like this (don't worry its just test data so no real passwords :P)...

```
[

{
    "$id": "1",
    "UserId": 1,
    "CreateDate": "2012-11-18T21:46:56.78",
    "ConfirmationToken": null,
    "IsConfirmed": true,
    "LastPasswordFailureDate": null,
    "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess": 0,
    "Password": "AIGvGbJIedgTyY+m08DCVhZbVnRTWzW6kvl1JMOqsFqOCSjnJTBlGUGmVveAYIONJw==",
    "PasswordChangedDate": "2012-11-18T21:46:56.78",
    "PasswordSalt": "",
    "PasswordVerificationToken": null,
    "PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate": null
},
{
    "$id": "2",
    "UserId": 2,
    "CreateDate": "2012-11-18T21:48:05.067",
    "ConfirmationToken": null,
    "IsConfirmed": true,
    "LastPasswordFailureDate": null,
    "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess": 0,
    "Password": "ACeoUpOVNEvgumvmSkFziRkNQzTlZC8+KAy32egXQseKLmhmJGX/VDXRXylkBUph3Q==",
    "PasswordChangedDate": "2012-11-18T21:48:05.067",
    "PasswordSalt": "",
    "PasswordVerificationToken": null,
    "PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate": null
},
{
    "$id": "3",
    "UserId": 3,
    "CreateDate": "2012-11-19T00:35:49.163",
    "ConfirmationToken": null,
    "IsConfirmed": true,
    "LastPasswordFailureDate": null,
    "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess": 0,
    "Password": "AF7W+1FNLcaA2qJ3nmrB7S9mkJmJGZCpAZYbyH5+iXryq1epr8i67ddgSbvFQF1bQw==",
    "PasswordChangedDate": "2012-11-19T00:35:49.163",
    "PasswordSalt": "",
    "PasswordVerificationToken": null,
    "PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate": null
},
{
    "$id": "4",
    "UserId": 4,
    "CreateDate": "2012-11-19T00:39:00.667",
    "ConfirmationToken": null,
    "IsConfirmed": true,
    "LastPasswordFailureDate": null,
    "PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess": 0,
    "Password": "ABPdfSj8jZAWqhHMDuTVQuL3AiEmiplSujA/GNjQoGoMQm0zhNwAAOaInbqrXFrM0g==",
    "PasswordChangedDate": "2012-11-19T00:39:00.667",
    "PasswordSalt": "",
    "PasswordVerificationToken": null,
    "PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate": null
}
```

]

Here is the raw unformatted JSON

```
[{"$id":"1","pb_Priority":{"$id":"2","pb_Projects":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$id":"3","pb_Priority":{"$ref":"2"},"pb_Tasks":[],"PROJECT_ID":2,"USER_ID":2,"NAME":"test2","DESCRIPTION":"test2","BUDGET":1.0,"LOCATION":"test","START_DATE":"2012-11-18T00:00:00","PRIORITY_ID":1,"PROJ_SCALE":null,"NOTES":null}],"PRIORITY_ID":1,"PRIORITY_LEVEL":1},"pb_Tasks":[{"$id":"4","pb_Projects":{"$ref":"1"},"TASK_ID":1,"PROJECT_ID":1,"USER_ID":1,"DUE_DATE":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","PRIORITY_ID":1,"TASK_NAME":"asdf","DESCRIPTION":"adsf"},{"$id":"5","pb_Projects":{"$ref":"1"},"TASK_ID":2,"PROJECT_ID":1,"USER_ID":2,"DUE_DATE":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","PRIORITY_ID":1,"TASK_NAME":"sdf","DESCRIPTION":"asd"},{"$id":"6","pb_Projects":{"$ref":"1"},"TASK_ID":3,"PROJECT_ID":1,"USER_ID":2,"DUE_DATE":"2012-11-19T00:00:00","PRIORITY_ID":2,"TASK_NAME":"dsf","DESCRIPTION":"asdf"}],"PROJECT_ID":1,"USER_ID":1,"NAME":"test","DESCRIPTION":"test","BUDGET":null,"LOCATION":"test","START_DATE":"2012-11-18T00:00:00","PRIORITY_ID":1,"PROJ_SCALE":null,"NOTES":null},{"$ref":"3"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using EF, by default, it will lazy load all the data from navigation properties. When serializer serializes model, it will visit each property on your model and EF will load all nested data.

As a best practice, you shouldn't expose your DB model as web api model. You'd better create another DTO model which you can control exactly what will be returned to client and what you want to receive from client.

Or you can quickly workaround it by hiding those navigation properties by modifier (mark them as internal), or using [IgnoreDataMember] attribute. It tells serializer not to visit them when serializing and deserilaizing.

Comment: well, i would like the objects to include the data from the navigation properties. Essentially like -Projects[ID, NAME -FK1[NAME, LOCATION]]. All the data i would like is in the object, just the view of it is a little obscure. Where can i read up on DTO model.

Comment: also, when i view just a single pb_project, it returns the result as expected, but not when viewing all the pb_projects. A single returns me, {

    "$id": "1",
    "pb_Priority": { … },
    "pb_Tasks": [ … ],
    "PROJECT_ID": 1,
    "USER_ID": 1,
    "NAME": "Project1",
    "DESCRIPTION": "project 1 description",
    "BUDGET": 1000,
    "LOCATION": "USA",
    "START_DATE": "2012-11-18T00:00:00",
    "PRIORITY_ID": 1,
    "PROJ_SCALE": null,
    "NOTES": null

}

Comment: is there anyway to turn off JSON.NET serializing objects by reference?

Comment: Sure, you can do that by: 
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

Comment: that worked somewhat. Now what I am getting when displaying all projects is a circular reference problem.  When the first project displays the priority also displays all projects that are included in that priority. So for example, i have priority 1,2,3 which values high, medium, low, If high exists in project 1 and 2, it gets displayed, where i only want to see the priority table associated with just that project (hard to explain)

Comment: That's why I don't recommend to expose navigation properties in web api model. Especially it has a deep object graph and one to many relationship. You should make any collection navigation property non-serializable. In this cause, you should hide Projects collection in Priority class by the methods that mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i learn by doing it haha. Are there any examples of where DTO are used in webapi. I know MVC and i used to use ViewModels, are DTO and ViewModels essentially the same idea? Also, I read that there are big advantages of using AutoMapper, is it worthwhile going this route?